# Wait until user is finished clicking | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to count the clicks while the user keeps clicking.
After about half a second when there are no more clicks on a specific button, the function should return the accumulated clicks.

I've tried it with this but, doesn't really work:

**HTML**:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="label" @click="cntNav">Next</a>
```

**JavaScipt**:

```
cntNav(element){
   let btn = element.target
   let cnt = 0
   let t = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(cnt)
   }, 1000)

   btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      cnt++
   })
}
```

**Console Output** (after 5x clicking):

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to add a new event listener in an event listener callback, especially on the same element. I suppose what you want is, to count each click every time the user clicks, but only log or display the accumulated clicks after a certain period of inactivity?

Comment: @Terry yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a timeout to delay returning the clicks.

```js
const main = () => {
  new Clicker('#click-me', {
    timeout: 500,
    callback: (clicks) => console.log(`Clicks: ${clicks}`)
  });
};

class Clicker {
  constructor(selector, options) {
    this.reference = typeof selector === 'string' ?
      document.querySelector(selector) : selector;
    let opts = Object.assign({}, Clicker.defaultOptions, options);
    this.timeout = opts.timeout;
    this.callback = opts.callback;
    this.initialize();
  }
  
  initialize() {
    this.__clickCount = 0;
    this.__activeId = null;
    this.reference.addEventListener('click', e => this.handleClick())
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    this.__clickCount += 1;
    clearTimeout(this.__activeId); // Reset the timeout
    this.__activeId = setTimeout(() => {
      this.callback(this.__clickCount);
      this.__clickCount = 0; // Reset clicks
    }, this.timeout);
  }
}

Clicker.defaultOptions = {
  timeout: 1000
};

main();
```

```html
<button id="click-me">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: @IronicUsername OOP is the best way to reuse logic and add extensibility. ;)

Comment: didn't really use it in an OOP way, since I use it once in the code haha. just took out the stuff from `initialize` and `handleClick` and added the event listener to the button onload haha
but still helped me :P

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<button onclick="cntNav();">Click Me!</button>
```

JS:

```
var cnt = 0;
var myTimeOut;
cntNav = function(){
   clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
   myTimeOut = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(cnt);cnt=0;
   }, 1000)
   cnt++;
}
```

This removes the timeout whenever someone clicks, so if someone clicks before the timeout has called, then it will be cleared. It will only call when someone leaves enough time in-between clicks. This then also sets the count back to zero.